# PHP website not working on local after Git clone

Tags: php, git, github, easyphp

I'm trying to clone a website on my local. It's a php website.

I have EasyPHP installed and in `easyphp/data/localweb/` i do `git clone` for my github repo.

So now i have `easyphp/data/localweb/**myproject**` . The `"myproject"` files contains the website and all the git files.

When I try to access my website via `localhost/myproject`, the PHP code isn't interpreted at all and I don't see the reason why. PHP works, but not inside this `git cloned` folder. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe the file extension is not `.php`

Comment: Maybe u don't have an `.index.php` inside ur `webroot`?

Comment: I do have, but any PHP code I type it's not interpreted.

Answer (score 1):

there can be so many things, starting with the configuration files, configuration of your local sever, from apache, php ... and many other possibilities 
it would be helpful if you could post the error message you're getting
also you could check your project config file, maybe you're using a db connection, but you do not have it set locally ... maybe you're using mode_rewrite on the project but not have it activated locally and so on ... could be httaccess 
but without an error message it's very difficult to tell

Comment: Let's say I have only 1 php file. Only index.php with an echo inside. I have no errors output and the apache/php logs are clean... It's something related to GIT but i'm not so familiar...

Comment: have you tried: http://localhost/myproject/index.php ? silly question: is your apache up and running?, git is not responsible that your index.php file is not interpreted in the browser. are you using xampp or wamp or a custom apache & php installation?

Comment: EasyPHP. It's not interpreting php code only in the folder that contains GIT, so only in the project I've cloned. It works in a separate folder.

Comment: I see, I've never used easyphp before, only wamp and xampp, so I just checked it out, and it's supposed to make use of wamp environment. are you using virtual hosts by any chance? if you make another folder and put an index php with phpinfo() in it does it work?